# Setting Default Font Family for kendo-angular-editor

Tags: kendo-ui, font-family, kendo-editor

How can I set default font to Roboto of the kendo-editor in Angular.

Comment: Try this, https://www.telerik.com/forums/default-font-and-fontsize

Comment: this is done in JQuery but cant do it in angular.

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I asked on telerik forums and got the answer it's all explained here

Just set the **[iframe]=false** on editor in HTML

and then in your css file define this:

```
.k-editor .k-editor-content {
  font-family: Roboto;
}
```

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/editor/styling/#toc-customizing-the-appearance